# What "kind" of writing is The Fixation of Belief essay by Charles Sanders Pierce?

Tags: style, academic-writing, essay

I happened by this essay a couple of years ago, now. I've been trying to find things written in a similar *style* since. However, I'm not terribly familiar with writing analysis, terminology, categorizing, et cetera. So I haven't really been able to to describe the attributes that I like about the essay well enough to find similar writings.

To clarify, clearly this is non-fiction. That's not what I'm asking. Also, it's clear to me that the subject of the essay is primarily epistemology. What I mean by style is more like cadence, I guess, seemingly unusual use of many comas for expressing nested thoughts, tone, maybe, and how he talks to the reader. I'm also not entirely sure if it would be considered academic writing. Is it?

Full text: [Fixation of Belief](http://www.peirce.org/writings/p107.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As.the title of the original publishing journal, *Popular Science Monthly* [1], shows "The Fixation of Knowledge" is an article "interpreting science for a broad audience". That is, it is popular science [2], in this case philosophy, or to be more precise, pragmatism [3].

There are countless pop science journals and monographs in all disciplines. You should be easily able to find more than you can ever read in any library or bookstore.

The writing style is that of the nineteenth century. If you read science from around that time it will be written in a similar ductus [4].

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_Science
[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_science
[3] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatism
[4] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductus_(linguistics)

Comment: 'Nineteenth century ductus' is what I was primarily looking for. The other details are helpful as well. Thanks.